# How do I read XML in TSQL using sp_xml_preparedocument that includes a namespace without prefix?

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, t-sql, xquery

I'm running SQL Server 2019 15.0.2095.3 and I want to read the contents of an XML file to then store it into a table. The problem is that I am not receiving any errors, but the result set is empty when the XML contains a namespace without prefix, but as soon as I remove the prefixless namespace it returns data again (it does work with prefix).

Here is the code to replicate the problem:

```
DECLARE @idoc INT, @doc VARCHAR(1000);   
SET @doc =' 
<ROOT xmlns="http://test.com">  
<Customers>  
   <Orders>  
      <nr>5</nr>
      <line>
        <test>55</test>
        <test2>444</test2>
      </line>
   </Orders>  
</Customers>  
<Customers>  
   <Orders>    
      <nr>4</nr>
      <line>
        <test>44</test>
        <test2>444</test2>
      </line>
   </Orders>  
</Customers>  
</ROOT>';   
  
--Create an internal representation of the XML document.  
EXEC sp_xml_preparedocument @idoc OUTPUT, @doc, '<ROOT xmlns="http://test.com"/>  '
  
-- SELECT statement that uses the OPENXML rowset provider.  
    SELECT *
    FROM       OPENXML (@idoc, '/ROOT/Customers/Orders/nr' ) 

EXEC sp_xml_removedocument @idoc;
```

When you remove the namespace `<ROOT xmlns="http://test.com">` and just use the element without it as so: `<ROOT>` it will return a normal result set.

**However I want the query to return the contents without changing the XML**

Comment: If you're using SQL Server 2019, why aren't you using XQuery? SQL Server has supported it since at least 2005. Then you can just within you namespace with  `WITH XMLNAMESPACES` clause.

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft proprietary `OPENXML()` and its companions `sp_xml_preparedocument` and `sp_xml_removedocument` are kept just for backward compatibility with the obsolete SQL
Server 2000. Their use is diminished just to very few fringe cases.

Starting from SQL Server 2005 onwards, it is strongly recommended to re-write your SQL and switch it to XQuery.
Also, OPENXML() cannot take advantage of XML indexes while XQuery methods can.

**SQL**

```
DECLARE @xml XML;   
SET @xml =
N'<ROOT xmlns="http://test.com">  
<Customers>  
   <Orders>  
      <nr>5</nr>
      <line>
        <test>55</test>
        <test2>444</test2>
      </line>
   </Orders>  
</Customers>  
<Customers>  
   <Orders>    
      <nr>4</nr>
      <line>
        <test>44</test>
        <test2>444</test2>
      </line>
   </Orders>  
</Customers>  
</ROOT>';   

;WITH XMLNAMESPACES(DEFAULT 'http://test.com')
SELECT c.value('(nr/text())[1]', 'INT') AS nr
    , c.value('(line/test/text())[1]', 'INT') AS test
    , c.value('(line/test2/text())[1]', 'INT') AS test2
FROM @xml.nodes('/ROOT/Customers/Orders') AS t(c);
```

**Output**

```
+----+------+-------+
| nr | test | test2 |
+----+------+-------+
|  5 |   55 |   444 |
|  4 |   44 |   444 |
+----+------+-------+
```